# Javascript collect value from input through the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field, who go through the loop and give me this result:
 [image]

Here is the code part:

```
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right;">
    <input type="text" id="comment" name="com" placeholder="Enter comment">
</td>
```

This part gives me input fields as many as products have added to the cart, that's why they through the loop.

Then I try to collect these entered values with this:

```
var comment = document.getElementsByName("com").value;
```

and send it forward with this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "/content/shop/order_process/ajax_checkout_create.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "item_comment="+encodeURIComponent(comment),
                success: function(answer)
        {
            if(answer.status == true)
            {
                <?php
                if($user_id != 0)
                {
                    ?>
                    location = "/shop/orders/order?order_id="+answer.order_id+"&success_message="+encodeURI("Order created");
                    <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                    location = "/shop/orders/orders-without-reg";
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            }
            else
            {
                alert(answer.message);
                
                document.getElementById("confirm_loader").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("confirm_btn").style.display = 'inline';
                
                return false;
            }
        }
});
```

and the final part is here in this file `/content/shop/order_process/ajax_checkout_create.php`

There is a code that needs to collect all entered values and store in database:

```
    if( !empty($_POST["item_comment"]) )
{
    $item_comment = trim($_POST["item_comment"]);
    $item_comment = htmlentities($item_comment);
    $item_comment = str_replace("\r","",$item_comment);
    $item_comment = str_replace("\t","",$item_comment);
    $item_comment = str_replace("\n","<br/>",$item_comment);

        $db_link->prepare('INSERT INTO `shop_orders_items_comment` (`order_id`, `order_item_id`, `text`) VALUES (?,?,?);')->execute( array($order_id, $order_item_id, $item_comment) );
}
```

For now, I can only get one comment, which is the first one, but how I can get all of them?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - You are rewriting same variable.
Second one, you have to send as array, there is how you can make an array:

```
<input type="text" name="com" placeholder="Enter comment">
<input type="text" name="com" placeholder="Enter comment">
<input type="text" name="com" placeholder="Enter comment">
<button onclick="parse_data();">parse</button>
<script>
function parse_data(){
    let elems = document.getElementsByName("com");
    let data = [];
    [...elems].forEach(function(item){
        if (item.value.length > 0){
            data.push(item.value);
        }
    });
    console.log(data);
}
</script>
```

then you have to send your item_comment as an array and proccess in PHP:

```
<?PHP
if (array_key_exists('item_comment', $_POST)){
    foreach($_POST['item_comment'] as $value){
        print($value.PHP_EOL);
    }
 }
```

for example:

```
curl -X POST -d "item_comment[]=1&item_comment[]=2" https://localhost/tests/form.php --insecure
```

will return:

```
1
2
```

Its just examples, you should rework for your code